# Need workaround for calling alert() from background script

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Calling alert() from the background script is allowed in Google's Chrome, but not in Firefox (WebExtensions) which I am porting my Chrome extension to.

So, I need a workaround to get an alert dialog up.  I'm not asking for anything else other than THE alert dialog.

Sending a message to a content script to call alert() will not suffice since no content scripts may be loaded at the time the alert call is needed.

Comment: The way that you have worded this it sounds like you will accept no solution other than the **actual** `alert()` dialog, not even something that looks and feels like it. If so, then you are SOL. The text which is output in the console "alert() is not supported in background windows; please use console.log instead." is clear. `alert()` is not supported in background scripts. If you want more information, you might check [Bug 1203394 - alert() does not work in background scripts](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1203394) which is RESOLVED FIXED with this console output as the result.

Comment: To be clear: Will you accept a substitute which works in both Firefox and Google Chrome which comes close to looking and acting like an `alert()`?

Comment: Also to be clear: it is not acceptable to you to have as a solution that a content script be loaded to accomplish the `alert()`. This is not saying send a message to an already loaded content script, but actually loading one specifically to handle this issue. This is not an acceptable solution to you, correct?

Comment: @Makyen Give it a shot.

Comment: @Makyen I know alert() is not supported in bg scripts.  That's why the question is asking for a **workaround**.  Clear?

Comment: But then you say "*I'm not asking for anything else other than THE alert dialog.*" That statement contradicts looking for a workaround that gives a reasonable feel to the user that is close to an `alert()` dialog. It implies the only thing that is acceptable to you is "THE alert dialog" and you want some way to trigger *that* code within a background script (unlikely to happen). That statement is why I asked for clarification. If you want something that is *close* to an `alert()` dialog, then that is possible.

Comment: @Makyen, you're making rash unimaginative assumptions.  If you can't answer the question as stated, don't let that bother you; just move along.

Answer (score 5):

My workaround is to save the alert code in a string like:

```
var alertWindow = 'alert(message)';
```

and let the background script inject that code like:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({code : alertWindow});
```

Comment: This hack does not work, when the active tab is e.g. an "about:" page, new tab and other similar situations, and that's precisely where I need to show an error message and suggestion how to work around the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Note that you need host permissions to inject into the current page. Thankfully, most of the time `activeTab` permission is sufficient. gregko's use case needs more work, however. An option would be to open a visible extension page for this in case the injection fails; clunky for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Background scripts and pages in Firefox unfortunately do not support the `prompt()`, `alert()` and `confirm()` functions of the DOM `window` object ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts#dom_apis)). However, a pretty good replacement for the `alert()` function is the [`browser.notifications` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Notifications).

To create a drop-in replacement, add the `notifications` permission to your `manifest.json`:

```json
  "permissions": [
      "notifications"
  ]
```

And add a function like this to your background script:

```js
function alert(msg) {
    browser.notifications.create({
        type : 'basic',
        message : msg,
        title : 'Extension alert'
    });
}
```

Now, whenever you call `alert()` in your extensions background script it will show a notification.