# How to pass value from JavaScript to text popup?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JS. I have a script that reads selected text on a web page and returns converted text. I am able to log this to the console fine, but I need this to be displayed as a popup text box instead. How can I do that?

I tried using `alert()`, bit it is not supported on background windows (at least on firefox).
Console log:
`alert() is not supported in background windows; please use console.log instead.`

Sorry for the noob question. Please let me know if I can include anything else which might be of help

Comment: use `alert("your text");` https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAgd4.jpg

Comment: Maybe you want to use alert box?

Comment: Tried. Alert is not supported on background windows.
I am using firefox

Comment: @SiddhantSadangi I tried on Firefox, it work https://i.stack.imgur.com/da0Dn.jpg see image linked, what you mean by "background window"?

Comment: I get the below error:  
alert() is not supported in background windows; please use console.log instead.

I want this functionality on external web pages, not locally hosted ones.

Comment: maybe try see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950281/need-workaround-for-calling-alert-from-background-script

Comment: [Sweet Alert Guide](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) go through this page, It will help you & As @LaaouatniAnas said, Alert will be the best as you're new to js

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas - that discussion didn't really lead anywhere :)
The top-voted answer doesn't work.

Comment: @Sakil - Sweet Alerts requires a bit of setup (npm, browserify, etc).. No out of the box JS/HTML solution available? I don't want fancy CSS too.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have enough reputation to make this a comment*

You can make a custom modal to show your result. Read this to help get that:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to execute inline scripts within HTML files. How do I use this from an HTML with a script source?

Comment: you can use the `<script>` tag to add js in an HTML page

```
<script>
The code here
</script>
```

Comment: At least on Firefox, inline scripts are blocked

Comment: `<script src="path_to_your_script.js"></script>`

Comment: I am using this. But this does not open the modal.
Just to add, I want to display the popup on an external web page (for example, facebook), when a text in a text input box is selected.. Something like the Grammarly or google translate browser extensions

Comment: I am not sure I understand you no more, but, I think, answers from this question may give you a head way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096438/how-to-make-chrome-extension-like-grammarly

Comment: Thanks.. this looks promising.. will give it a shot!